# Does the Star Trek `reboot` mean that Star Trek TNG (et. al.) never happened?

Tags: star-trek

I've been afraid to care very much for the "reboot".

Does the Star Trek Movie reboot mean that Star Trek TNG (et. al.) never happened?

If so, the implications of liking it are that I put aside my beloved series. (Although the pacing on Voyager's final episode was so wrong that I felt betrayed.)

What does it mean? What are the implications that I haven't thought of? Thanks!

Comment: None of Star Trek ever happened. It is fiction. Captain Picard is played by an actor named Patrick Stewart. Accordingly, you are free to enjoy watching your ST:TNG DVDs with no emotional conflict. [Takes cover, awaits slings and arrows of outraged Trekkies.]

Comment: Bandit, only mental people think it's real. The whole point is the 'willing suspension of disbelief'. That's why purely out of universe answers are frowned upon.

Comment: @Richard: The question said, "the implications of liking it are that I put aside my beloved series". That's an out-of-universe issue, so it requires an out-of-universe answer. :-)

Comment: I **was** joking in my original comment. But taking the question seriously for a second: The year 2001 came and went without anyone finding an alien monolith on the Moon. It is now completely impossible for the events of *2001: A Space Odyssey* to come true. So what? That doesn't mean anybody has to "put aside" the movie.

Comment: Hold on. You meant to say it hasn't happened yet, right? o.O